# Upload File Validation using jQuery Forms in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on some ASP.NET MVC code which makes use of the jQuery Forms plug-in to allow users to upload files.

The Form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAttachments", "Data", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id="SaveAttachments" })) {%>   
        <input type="file" name="consentform" size=30/>
     <input type="file" name="infosheet" size=30/>     
     <input type="file" name="approval" size=30 />         
<%} %>
```

The form is submitted using jQuery with the Form plugin:

```
$('#SaveAttachments").ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function(html, status) {
                        $("#response").append(html);
                    }
});
```

It is handled by a controller action name SaveAttachments:

```
public ActionResult SaveAttachments(HttpPostedFileBase consentform, HttpPostedFileBase infosheet, HttpPostedFileBase approval)
        {
            string message = SaveFiles(consentform, infosheet, approval)
            return Content(message);
        }
```

This works well except in the case of errors which prevent the controller action from being called; Specifically when the file size is too large and a HttpException "Maximum Request Length is Exceeded" is thrown.

What I require is a way of updating the user with a suitable message when such errors occur.

I have considered the following:

1. Try and use the Forms plugin to
   detect and handle this within the ajaxSubmit() - this
   doesn't appear possible.
2. Add some client side validation on
   the files to upload - without using
   Flash or ActiveX, I can't find a way
   of checking file size etc. in IE and FF.
3. Handle the HttpException thrown by the Controller.Execute() method, and
   communicate this with the
   SaveAttachments() action - I was
   considering overriding the
   controller.Execute() method to allow
   this.

What is the best method of achieving the necesary validation, and if there is no clean way is handling the exception an acceptable workaround?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have been reduced to two options:

1. Use Flash/ActiveX/Silverlight for
   more versatile file upload form.
2. Find a way to direct text from the
   content length exceeded exception
   handler to the  displaying the
   status in the form. As the file upload form is
   submitted using an iFrame I'm not
   sure I can do this..

Comment: I had/have the same problem. I dont want to use Flash/ActiveX/Silverlight either (i wrote a jQuery ajax multi-file uploader). From experience: You can't know the content length before you post so there is no way to check the file length client side. And by the time the action barfs once receiving too many bytes you might as well return the status to the client then, trying to do it ajax seems pointless to me. I simply specify on the UI that each file must be smaller than a certain length. NB: when i upload multiple files, i dont suffer from the same length limitation for the sum of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use jQuery's ajaxError function?
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback

Also, you may want to be more specific about which plugin you are using. ajaxSubmit() is not core jquery.

Comment: I'm using the Form plugin. I've editted my post to make this more obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately the MVC framework throws the content length exception before the Post is made. As a result the jQuery ajax stuff never gets a returned result.